# Kotlin: How to change values of MutableLiveData in ViewModel without using getters and setters

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

Here is my viewmodel:

```
class MyProfileEditSharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val question = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val answer = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setQuestion (q: String) {
        question.value = q
    }

    fun setAnswer (a: String) {
        answer.value = a
    }
}
```

I set the data using setQuestion and setAnswer like this:

```
viewModel.setQuestion(currentUserInList.question)
viewModel.setAnswer(currentUserInList.answer)
```

I try to get question and answer from the ViewModel like this:

```
val qnaQuestionData = communicationViewModel.question as String
val qnaAnswerData = communicationViewModel.answer as String
```

Compiler says I cannot cast MutableLiveData to string.
Should I make a separate getter like my setter? I heard that you don't need to use getters and setters in kotlin, is there anyway to edit val question and val answer in my viewmodel without using getters and setters?

Thank you!!

Comment: You should be observing `LiveData` to get notified of changes in it, and not pulling data manually. See the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects

Comment: You would use something like `val qnaQuestionData = communicationViewModel.question.value ?: someDefault`, but typically you don't want to be retrieving a LiveData's value synchronously because it defeats the purpose of using LiveData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast it to `String` because the type of object is `MutableLiveData`, but you can access the value with `.value` property

```kotlin
val qnaQuestionData = communicationViewModel.question.value
val qnaAnswerData = communicationViewModel.answer.value
```

in this case, may facing errors about `MutableLiveData` initialization.

another way is observing the LiveData for changes:

```kotlin
communicationViewModel.question.observe(this, Observer{ data->
 ...
})
```

Or if you have not accessed to any lifecycle owner

```kotlin
communicationViewModel.question.observeForever(Observer{ data->
 ...
})
```

but please remember to remove the observer through `removeObserver` method

- for setting the values it's better to use properties directly or binding way

```kotlin
communicationViewModel.question.postValue("some new value")
```

Or

```kotlin
communicationViewModel.question.value = "some new value"
```

- **Suggestion** for MutableLiveData properties:

```kotlin
val question: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
val answer: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData

Answer (score 1):

Create some sort of getter method in your ViewModel

```
fun getQuestion(): LiveData<String> {
        return question //this works because MutableLiveData is a subclass of LiveData
}
```

Then, you can observe the value in whatever class you care about the value. ie:

```
communicationsViewModel.getQuestion().observe(this, Observer {
       //do something with the value which is 'it'. Maybe qnaQuestionData = it
}
```

Note if you're trying to observe the value from a fragment or something, you will have to change the parameter this, to viewLifecycleOwner

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using getters and setters?

Comment: Make the `MutableLiveData` property private and make another property that casts it as `LiveData`. For example, `private val _question = MutableLiveData<String>(); val question: LiveData<String> = _question`